# SKSpriteNode collision not being recognized fast enough

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have an SKSpriteNode ("Known as ball") that is launched by applying an impulse to its physicsBody. In my didBeginContact method, I check to see if the node collided with an obstacle. If it did, I want the SKSpriteNode to stop moving immediately (e.g. "stick" to the object it collided with). The problem is, by the time it is realized that the ball has collided with the obstacle and the ball's velocity is set to 0, the ball has already rebounded, and instead of touching the obstacle it collided with, it is now 30 or so pixels away

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {       
    ballInMidAir = false
    var firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Obstacle && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Ball){
        (secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode).removeAllActions()
        secondBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        (secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode).runAction(SKAction.moveBy(obstacleVector, duration: 9.0))
    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.ObstacleStill && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Ball){
        (secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode).removeAllActions()
        secondBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    }
}
```

In theory I could calculate the point at which the ball *should* collide with the obstacle and just move the ball to that point after the collision, but all the most of the obstacles are actively moving around, so that would be extremely difficult. Anybody have a solution? Thanks in advance (:

Comment: Two questions: 1) What precision are you using for the relevant physics bodies? I've had some success tinkering with that in situations where it's a computational issue. 2) What shape do the relevant bodies have? It's a horrible kludge, but you may be able to make the collisions happen sooner using physics bodies with larger radii or polygon dimensions than the base object.

Comment: The ball is a circle, and the obstacles are rectangles. In this case, making the radii or polygon dimensions bigger wouldn't be a good idea, since the strength of the impulse applied to the ball varies

Comment: If the impulse is less, the ball will travel slower, and therefore go less far in between the time is "collides" and when it actually stops. Also I'm not sure about the precision. I have to figure out how to edit that in xcode

Comment: Pleasant is most likely correct, just set usesPreciseCollisionDetection: true on one or both of the physics nodes.

Comment: That helped a bit. Thanks! Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem - the ball still bounces away from the obstacle a little before it stops. By not as much, but still a noticeable amount.

Comment: Try setting `collisionBitMask = 0` for the ball's and/or obstacle's physics body

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. Im surprised there isn't an easy way to get two objects to stick to each other when they collide, even at fast speeds

Comment: If you set the `collisionBitMask = 0` for both bodies, the ball should pass through the obstacle not bounce off it.

Comment: Yeah that's what happened

Comment: Perhaps you can slow the ball prior to the contact. BTW, you should use @user_name when replying so that person gets a notification.

Comment: @Lahav As I can see you are mixing actions with physics simulation. You have to be aware that physics engine and SKAction don't play well together if you are interested in physics simulation. When moving physics body by actions you are pulling it out from physics simulation.

Comment: @Whirlwind well if you're talking about the removeAllActions() part, I just put that in there because I want the node to stop changing colors

Comment: @Lahav I am talking about SKAction.moveBy() part... . If you are just interested in contact detection, then moving objects with SKAction is safe. But if you are interested in collisions and other physics behaviours, then actions are not good choice.

Comment: @Whirlwind I'm a little confused about the difference between contact detection and collisions. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Lahav By contact I mean triggering didBeginContact method when two bodies make contact. This can be triggered even if you move objects (with physics bodies attached) by actions. Contact can be detected even if both bodies have their collisionBitMasks set to 0 (like 0x141E pointed).  By collision I mean preventing bodies to penetrate eachother  when contact is made.

Comment: @Whirlwind well in this case I am only interested in contact detection. Like I said, I want the ball to stop when it hits the obstacle

Comment: Well then as already suggested, ball's collisionBitMask should be set to prevent colliding with obstacle. When contact is detected, if you want ball to stop, you can set ball.physicsBody.velocity = CGVector(0,0). In the case you decide to move the ball without forces and use actions, then remove the "moving" action when contact is made.

Comment: @Whirlwind the problem is that I did exactly that, but there is a short delay between when they collide, and when the didBeginContact method recognizes that they collided. What happens in my program is that when collisionBitMask is set to 0, the ball only stops moving once it has entered the obstacle partially. When it is not set to zero, the ball only stops moving once it has rebounded a little bit. Not a lot, but a noticeable amount. 10 or 20 pixels.

Comment: Try adding a print statement in didbegincontact to see how fast the ball is moving when it hits the obstacle. It may be so fast it passes through the obstacle in less than a frame

Comment: Do you have visual physics representation enabled ? Is there everything okay with physics bodies sizes ? One idea for the case when you have collisionBitMask enabled is to try to play with restitution properties for both physics bodies. That property regulates bounciness. Try to set some low values, or even 0 to see what happens. Okay, good night, and good luck with your game ;)

Comment: You may need to predict when a collision will occur

Comment: Setting the restitution property is a good idea. If that doesn't work, try examining the `SKPhysicsContact` object. It has the point where the contact was made. You can use this to re-position the ball after it hits the obstacle.

Comment: @0x141E  your idea of finding the point where they collide and repositioning the ball to that point worked very well! Thanks! Its not perfect, but it gets the job done! It looks a tiny bit glitchy when it jumps back to the contactPoint, but beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: @Whirlwind For some reason, setting the restitution to 0 seemed to only help when the ball was traveling under a certain speed. The ball otherwise went straight through the object if it was going to fast. And thanks!

Comment: I just summarized the comments for developers who have the same issue and don't have time to read through the comments

Comment: Probably a good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas...

1. As CH Buckingham commented, it's a good idea to set the physics body's `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` to `true`  for fast moving sprites. From the docs,

> If this property is set to YES on either body, the simulation performs a more precise and more expensive calculation to detect these collisions. This property should be set to YES on small, fast moving bodies.

2. As Whirlwind pointed out, setting the `restitution` property will affect the elasticity of the collision. Setting this to zero will prevent the ball from bouncing off the obstacle

> This property is used to determine how much energy the physics body
>   loses when it bounces off another object. The property must be a value
>   between 0.0 and 1.0. The default value is 0.2.

3. Setting the `collisionBitMask = 0` on one of the bodies will cause the ball to pass through the obstacles instead of bouncing off them
4. Re-positioning the ball using the `contactPoint` property of the `SKPhysicsContact` object, where `contactPoint` is the

> ... point between the two physics bodies [where the impact occurred], in
>   scene coordinates

You can also use the `collisionImpulse` property to determine

> [t]he impulse that specifies how hard these two bodies struck each other
>   in newton-seconds.

and the `normalVector` property that give the direction of the collision.